# Recursion Error Using PuLP

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, pulp

I'm currently building a code that can translate an existing mixed-integer linear programming tableau matrix into a PuLP-compatible model.  Although this program works on one computer, it has repeatedly failed due to a maximum recursion depth error on another.  Both computers use the a maximum recursion depth of 1000.  The model this code is copying is not large, as it is a test model that has approximately 250 variables and 90 constraints.

The code produces the x variables and the objective function of the model, but fails during the first iteration of the block of code used to produce empty constraints.  The constraints of the model do not return a value

```
 # Import PuLP modeler functions
from pulp import *

# base model
model = LpProblem("MASTRS_LP",LpMinimize)

# shape of existing tableau matrix
[m,n]=np.shape(A)

# positive X variables
xVar = {}
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if i-1 in e[:,1]:      # if i is in array holding indexes of integer variables
        xVar[i] = LpVariable(name='xNodeI_%s' % (i),lowBound=0, upBound=1,cat=LpInteger) #Integers
    else:
        xVar[i] = LpVariable(name='xRoute_%s' % (i),lowBound=0, upBound=None,cat=LpContinuous) # Routes

# Objective Function
model += lpSum([0]), "Sum of Total Supply Chain"
for i in range(1,n):
    model.objective.addterm(xVar[i+1], c[0,i])

# Constraints
for i in range(0,m):
    # Create empty constraint 
    if s[i]==1:
        model += lpSum([0]) <= b[i]
    if s[i]==0:
        model += lpSum([0]) == b[i]
    if s[i]==-1:
        model += lpSum([0]) >= b[i]

    # add variables to constraint
    for j in range(0,n):
        if A[i,j]!=0:
            model.constraints['_C'+str(i+1)].addterm(xVar[j+1], A[i,j])  

# delete existing transshipment variables
del A,b,s,c

# solve transshipment model
status = model.solve()
```

The top line of the error is repeated many times,

the error looks like:

```
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py", line 735, in subInPlace
    self.subInPlace(e)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py", line 735, in subInPlace
    self.subInPlace(e)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py", line 733, in subInPlace
    or isinstance(other, Iterable)):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\abc.py", line 132, in __instancecheck__
    if subclass is not None and subclass in cls._abc_cache:
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\_weakrefset.py", line 75, in __contains__
    return wr in self.data
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would change the way generate constraints and the objective

```
# Constraints
for i in range(0,m):
   # Create constraint lhs
   lhs = lpSum([A[i,j] * xVar[j+1] for j in range(0,n) if A[i,j]])
   if s[i]==1:
       model += lhs <= b[i]
   if s[i]==0:
       model += lhs == b[i]
   if s[i]==-1:
       model += lhs >= b[i]
```